# nginx server block proxy pass issue

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

i have a node application running over my ubuntu server over 4000 port with domain example.com. Then i created a server block inside my nginx config to run my angular app with backend as node. So in my angular app my node server is running over 3001.I will show the nginx config of this

```
server {
        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
      server_name example.com www.example.com;

location / {
        #  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                client_max_body_size 200M;
                                                        }
location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        client_max_body_size 200M;
    }

location /app2 {
    alias /var/www/html/app2;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /app2/index.html;
  }

location /assets/ {
        alias /var/www/html/app2/assets/;
        expires 1h;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


                listen 80;
                listen [::]:80;
            server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

So im able to access my angular app over example.com/app2, but im not able to make a request from my angular app using example.com/api/ as defined in the server block. Im getting NOT FOUND 404. i guess nginx is not forwarding the request to 3001 port on which my node for angular app is running

i have checked whether my node server is running or not.

made a curl request from my server such as localhost:3001 and im getting the response fine but cant make a request such as curl example.com/api/.

The url i defined in my angular app is https://example.com/api. for example if i try to make a request as https://example.com/api/login to my node server where i have route as router.post("/login"), it will end up in NOT FOUND 404

Comment: So `https://example.com/api/login` should be passed to `http://localhost:3001/login`? With the `/api/` part removed? At the moment you are passing the request as `http://localhost:3001/api/login` - try using `proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;` (by adding a trailing `/`)

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for replying Richard, I tried to add a trailing / but I'm getting a bad gateway error in my console

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching the locations for the reasons explained in [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

For instance, like this:

```
server {
        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
      server_name example.com www.example.com;

                                                        }
location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        client_max_body_size 200M;
    }

location /app2 {
    alias /var/www/html/app2;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /app2/index.html;
  }

location / {
        #  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                client_max_body_size 200M;
```

i think `example.com/api/foo` can match the first location you defined, and that's causing `404`.

hope this helps!